# Why Schlimmstes but no Schlimmster?

Tags: gender, nominalization, comparison, definiteness

Das Schlimmste is [frequently used without an article](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=zeit&q=%40Schlimmstes) like this:

> Bürgermeister Marques befürchtet für seinen Ort Schlimmstes.
> Man vermutet Schlimmstes.
> Es ist Schlimmstes zu befürchten.

But der Schlimmste is [never used without an article](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=%40der%20%40Schlimmste&corpus=zeit&date-start=1946&date-end=2018&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=50):

> Das ist der Schlimmste.

not

> Das ist Schlimmster.

---

> Ich hatte Fieber, der Flug war der Schlimmste meines Lebens.

not

> Ich hatte Fieber, der Flug war Schlimmster meines Lebens.

Why is this true?

Comment: https://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/AdjectivalNouns/AdjectivalNouns.html seems to be a good introduction.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, that reference does not specifically address my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Wir erwarten Schlimmstes."* means *"Wir erwarten **etwas**, das so schlimm ist, dass es nicht mehr weiter steigerbar ist. Wir wissen nicht, was genau."* Note the "etwas" (something) here, it's not clear, what bad thing is expected exactly. It's not 100% the same as *"das Schlimmste"*, in that *"das Schlimmste"* is definite.

*"Wir erwarten das Schlimmste."* means that the speaker is talking about something specific that is meant by *"das Schlimmste"*. It means *"Wir erwarten, dass das Schlimmste eintrifft. Wir wissen (grob), was das ist."*

Both of your examples for *"Schlimmster"* can't work because of that. You're trying to use it with a definite person and a definite flight.

That being said, if we wanted to use the male or female form of "Schlimmstes", your listeners would have to know that it refers to something or someone grammatically male or female that is implied. With "Schlimmstes", what is implied is "something" (that can be anything). With "Schlimmster" or "Schlimmste", there is no natural implication like that.

So that's the answer to the question. "Schlimmstes" implies "etwas" ("something"), which could be called the default neutral. There is no default male or female like that.

One addition: If you allow "schlimmster" or "schlimmste" to refer to a class of things or persons that has been mentioned before, but where you still want it to be indefinite, it can in fact be used:

> Tante Trude will zur Party Kuchen mitbringen. Wir erwarten schlimmsten.

> Onkel Willi hat versprochen, Musik aufzulegen. Wir erwarten schlimmste.

However, that's not the same as "Schlimmstes" of course because it's not used as a noun but as an adjective with a back reference. Also note how the nouns that are refered to are uncountable generic terms and already don't have articles.

Comment: There is a lot to unpack here, but I really appreciate all of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The word *»schlimm«* (bad, evil, ...) is an adjective, like *»gut«* (good), *»hässlich«* (ugly), *»arm«* (poor) or *»reich«* (rich). And in many languages adjectives can be nominalized, which means, they will be used not as adjectives but as nouns:

> The Rich and the Poor (Title of some books, articles and a song)
> The Good, the Bad and the Ugly (English title of the Italian Western *Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo*)

What works in English (and Italian) works also in German, but in German also the form of the word changes:

- definite

  > (m) Der Schlimme ist wieder da.
  > (f) Die Schlimme ist wieder da.
  > (n) Das Schlimme ist wieder da.
- indefinite

  > (m) Ein Schlimmer ist wieder da.
  > (f) Eine Schlimme ist wieder da.
  > (n) Ein Schlimmes ist wieder da.

Most adjectives can also be intensified:

- positive

  > Das schlimme Ereignis ist furchtbar.
  > Ein schlimmes Ereignis ist furchtbar.
  > Das Ereignis ist schlimm.
- comparative

  > Das schlimmere Ereignis ist furchtbar.
  > Ein schlimmeres Ereignis ist furchtbar.
  > Das Ereignis ist schlimmer.
- superlative

  > Das schlimmste Ereignis ist furchtbar.
  > Ein schlimmstes Ereignis ist furchtbar.
  > Das Ereignis ist am schlimmsten.

And those intensified adjectives can also be nominalized. The positive forms are already shown above.

- nominalized comparative adjective

  - definite

    > (m) Der Schlimmere ist wieder da.
    > (f) Die Schlimmere ist wieder da.
    > (n) Das Schlimmere ist wieder da.
  - indefinite

    > (m) Ein Schlimmerer ist wieder da.
    > (f) Eine Schlimmere ist wieder da.
    > (n) Ein Schlimmeres ist wieder da.
- nominalized comparative adjective

  - definite

    > (m) Der Schlimmste ist wieder da.
    > (f) Die Schlimmste ist wieder da.
    > (n) Das Schlimmste ist wieder da.
  - indefinite

    > (m) Ein Schlimmster ist wieder da.
    > (f) Eine Schlimmste ist wieder da.
    > (n) Ein Schlimmstes ist wieder da.

---

The next thing to know is, that the indefinite form does not always needs an article. For example the indefinite plural never has an article:

- singular definite: Der Baum wächst.
- singular indefinite: Ein Baum wächst.
- plural definite: Die Bäume wachsen.
- plural indefinite: Bäume wachsen.

And also nominalized adjectives often don't need an article when they are used indefinite:

- definite nominalized superlative adjective:

> Bürgermeister Marques befürchtet für seinen Ort **das Schlimmste.**

- indefinite nominalized superlative adjective:

  - with article (unusual, maybe even wrong?)

    > Bürgermeister Marques befürchtet für seinen Ort **ein Schlimmstes.**
  - without article (usual and correct)

    > Bürgermeister Marques befürchtet für seinen Ort **Schlimmstes.**

Instread of an article you can also have another determiner, for example an pronoun. If it is an indefinite pronoun, the adjective behaves as if there was an indefinite article:

- superlative with indefinite pronoun:

  > Man vermutet **etwas Schlimmstes.**
- superlative with indefinite article:

  > Man vermutet **ein Schlimmstes.**

But both versions are unusual. Normally you use this just without any determiner:

> Man vermutet **Schlimmstes.**

This is because superlative does not fit well with indefiniteness. There can only be one best, one worst and one ugliest, but being indefinite means to be just any, not something special.

So this is no problem at all:

- positive + definite

  > Es ist das Schlimme zu befürchten.
- comparative + definite

  > Es ist das Schlimmere zu befürchten.
- superlative + definite

  > Es ist das Schlimmste zu befürchten.
- positive + indefinite

  > Es ist etwas Schlimmes zu befürchten.
- comparative + indefinite

  > Es ist etwas Schlimmeres zu befürchten.

But when it comes to superlative, an indefinite determiner does not fit well. So you use the superlative without any determiner. And no determiner also indicates indefiniteness:

- superlative + indefinite

  > Es ist Schlimmstes zu befürchten.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly" is a literal translation and doesn't really work in English. It conveys the meaning with a bit of poetic license, but it shouldn't be used and an example. In English, nominalized adjectives are plural, so the title means something like "Good People, Bad People, and Ugly People", which doesn't describe the movie. A literal translation works much better is German, something like "*Der Gute, der Böse und der Hässliche*". The actual German title is "*Zwei glorreiche Halunken*"; I don't know about you but I can't say I like it much.